# How to alter Materialize's JS to look for classes instead of ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, materialize

Using Joomla with Materialize 0.97.6.

I currently having two major issues with Materialize on Joomla. First for the dropdown on navigation bars. It needs an ID to function but since an ID needs to be unique I can only have one of them.

The second one is with tabs. It also uses an ID to find the tab and display it but again I can only have one ID or the other ones won't function.

I have no experience with JavaScript or Jquery but can anyone help me on solving this issue?

**Here is a pen with the Materialize examples from a  navigation bar with dropdown and tabs:** https://codepen.io/chainboost/pen/kXZbdd?editors=1000

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>

      <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
          <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">

             <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
            <li class="active"> <a class='dropdown-button' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a></li>

            <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
            <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
              <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
              <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
            </ul>            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>


        <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
  </div>


      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? In the CodePen you provided, the dropdown and tabs function like they are supposed to.

Comment: @adriennetacke If I set this up in Joomla it uses the same ID so it won't function

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, unfortunately I do not have experience with Joomla to suggest any solutions.

Comment: @adriennetacke No problem!